# openxlsx in R - getSheetNames of files in a for loop

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have 3 files.

```
library(openxlsx)
file1 <- '/home/mycomp/file1.xlsx'
file2 <- '/home/mycomp/file2.xlsx'
file3 <- '/home/mycomp/file3.xlsx'

fil <- c(file1, file2,file3)
```

Each file has multiple sheets.  I am trying to print the sheeetNames from each file using a forloop.

```
for (i in fil) {
  sheets <- openxlsx:::getSheetNames(fil[i])
  for (s in sheets) {
    print(s)
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in getSheetNames(fil[i]) : file does not exist.
```

However when I run the file individually, I get the sheet names printed.

```
for (i in fil) {
  sheets <- openxlsx:::getSheetNames(file1)
  for (s in sheets) {
    print(s)
  }
}
```

In this case I get the sheet names printed 3 times as the `fil` contains 3 files.  Why does my forloop prints the error in earlier case.

Comment: What is the output if you add `print(fil[i])` before `sheets <- openxlsx:::getSheetNames(fil[i])`?

Comment: I get NA values

Comment: Got it... When i use `i` instead of `fil[i]` I am getting the correct output.

Comment: yes, `i` is the name of the file and not the index to subset from `fil`.

Comment: Use this instead `for (i in seq_along(fil))`. More info https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/15-supp-loops-in-depth/

Comment: @Tung Thank you....I can accept the seq_along as answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use i rather than fil[i].

```
 for (i in fil) {
        sheets <- openxlsx:::getSheetNames(i)
        for (s in sheets) {
            print(s)
        }
    }
```